# Need to know UP/DOWN arrow button is clicked while implementing QDateTimeEdit in Qt?

Tags: qt, qdatetime

Need to know UP/DOWN arrow button is clicked while implementing  `QDateTimeEdit` in Qt?

I want to catch which button UP/DOWN clicked while changing the time.
Please tell me the function which catches this signal.

Please reply me fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is quite simple.

To catch that you must create your own class inherited from `QDateTimeEdit` and reimplement 
`stepBy(int steps)` function.

So, your class will looks like:

```
class MyDateTime : public QDateTimeEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyDateTime(QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void stepBy(int steps);
};
```

And implementation of `void stepBy(int steps)`:

```
void MyDateTime::stepBy(int steps)
{
    // here you can do your own business
    if (steps!=0)
        qDebug( steps > 0
                ? "going up"
                : "going down" );
    // we must call it to provide QDateTimeEdit's
    // functionality
    QDateTimeEdit::stepBy(steps);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: please let me kno how can i rollback  min/sec from 59 to 00 or vice versa. Actually  QDateTimeEdit doesnt allows it by default and it get stuck after reaching maximum value of 59 if tried pressing up arrow and same for minium value 00.

Comment: You got answer for your question. That is another question.

Comment: Yes i got the answer for the first question. Now that was second query.. please help me in that.

Comment: One question per one thread. Please, mark this question as answered, and create new one, with your other question.

Comment: Ok fine. switching to new thread. Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212762/in-qdatetimeedit-how-to-rollback-from-59-to-00-or-vice-versa-in-section-minute

Comment: You got answer, aren't you? Mark as answered.

Comment: Thanx troyane, i am satisfied with your answer and i have accepted it. I will be thankfull agian if you answer my next query in new thread in last reply.