# QDateTimeEdit: rollback from 59 to 00 or vice-versa in hours/minute/second

Tags: qt, qdatetime

How can I rollback hour/min/sec from `59` to `00` or vice versa. Actually `QDateTimeEdit` doesn't allow it by default and it get stuck after reaching maximum value of `59` if tried pressing up arrow, and same for minimum value `00`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must know that `QDateTimeEdit` is inherit `QAbstractSpinBox`, and `QAbstractSpinBox` has wrapping mechanism, using it you can make your spins circular. So, all what you must do is

```
setWrapping(true)
```

in your case, it must be something like this: `ui->dateTimeEdit->setWrapping(true);`

If wrapping is `true` stepping up from `maximum()` value will take you to the `minimum()` value and vica versa. Wrapping only make sense if you have `minimum()` and `maximum()` values set.

See official documentation [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qabstractspinbox.html#wrapping-prop) .

Good luck!